# "Jurisdiction" between us and Open Source SE

Tags: discussion, scope

What are the types of questions that can be asked here vs Open Source SE? Is there any overlap? Do we want to answer open source questions?

Comment: Is the question on-topic here (i.e. Is it a legal question?) If yes, then it should be on-topic, and we want to answer them here. Don't worry about the scope of other communities in determining your scope. P.S. I'm an Open Source mod :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On-topic for [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> - Statutes or court decisions
> - Legal terms and language, doctrines and theory
> - Legal process and procedure
> - Historical legal applications
> - Dealing with legal professionals

On-topic for [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> You've come to the right place if you have questions about:
>
> - the history and philosophies of the FSF, OSI, CC etc
> - understanding, applying, and complying with Free & Open licenses
> - how communities collaborate together to produce, distribute, market and sometime monetize these projects
> - what license to use for a specific situation - but please read How do I ask for a license recommendation? first
>
> But there are some questions which should not be asked here:
>
> - if you want to know how to use some software, or how its code works (ask on Super User or Stack Overflow)
> - if you would like recommendations for Free/Open software or media (ask on Software Recommendations)

Now, it's probably best not to think about it as us vs them. Because really, there's *a lot* of potential overlap. We even have an [open-source-software](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source-software) tag. They have a [law](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) tag.

If a question is on-topic for one site, it isn't automatically off-topic for all others. In fact, even if a question would be *better* on one site, it isn't automatically off-topic for all others. Remember that the same question on different sites can get wildly different answers.

So here's ***my* recommendation**:

- **If a question is on-topic for Law** but it is also on-topic for another site **and it would likely get faster or better answers** then please comment stating that it can also be asked on that site.
- **If a question is off-topic for Law** *and it is on-topic for another site* then *unless it's uncontroversial* then please close as off-topic, and then either comment letting the asker know that the other site exists, and *once it's closed*, optionally flag it for moderator attention. The off-topic closure reason should probably be something like *"I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with law but is on topic at *some other site*"*.